# Author's words in Proverbs 5:20 compared to his way of living?

Tags: solomon, proverbs

> And why wilt thou, my son, be ravished with a strange woman, and embrace the bosom of a stranger? (Proverbs 5:20, KJV)

It is well-known that Solomon had many wives and concubines. It seems that the advice he is giving here contradicts to his own way of living. How is this seeming contradiction usually explained in Catholicism, Orthodoxy and main-stream Protestantism?

Comment: Solomon was a hypocritical failure? What else is there to reconcile or explain?

Comment: King Solomon's wisdom recorded in THE WORD OF GOD is not his 'opinion', it's the Word of God. Only truth made it onto the paper, whether the author knew it, liked it, was hypocritical (we don't know when he wrote it, or if he repented, by the way).

Comment: @SolaGratia - So, is it how this matter is explained in Christianity?

Comment: Mysterious down-voters, please, explain why you down-vote my question.

Comment: I'm Catholic, but I'm pretty sure most Christians would believe something along these lines; the Word of God, Scripture, is inspired by God in a special way, more than just containing the odd 'inspirational thought given by God.' So its author is out on the sidelines, the mere quill with which God is writing a message to mankind. No amount of hypocrisy or context is going to un-say what is said here. Solomon can still write was is proper or true, and no one is perfect. We are not actually sure who wrote some Books of the Bible, and so this is even more true with these Books.

Comment: @SolaGratia - "No amount of hypocrisy or context is going to un-say what is said here. Solomon can still write was is proper or true..." - It's true that there were cases when some characters in the Bible would say something that they totally didn't understand or even intend to say (for example, Balaam in Numbers 22–24), however, in most cases  the speakers realized what they were saying, especially if it was not a case of a prophesy, but a mere conversation or some kind of teaching or admonishment. There is no indication that the author of Proverbs doesn't understand what he is saying.

Comment: And it was not my intention to say Solomon was a robot, only that it was right that he write the inspired words he did.

Comment: @SolaGratia - "...only that it was right that he write the inspired words he did" - Which was not at all what I was asking about in my question.

Comment: I know, I'm just saying your question would seem to suggest a kind of divine inspiration equivalent of Donatism. Whereas Scripture itself shows that enemies of God can be inspired/recieve revelation. e.g. *John 11:49-51*. And also that we know Solomon continued in sin when he wrote this literature. Which we simply don't know.

Comment: @SolaGratia - Well, I never meant or implied that.

Answer (score 0):

> "And why wilt thou, my son, be ravished with a strange woman, and embrace the bosom of a stranger?" (Proverb 5:20)
>
> It is well-known that Solomon had many wives and concubines. It seems that the advice he is giving here contradicts to his own way of living.

There are no contradictions here because many wives and concubines were not "strangers" for king Solomon, they were his.

In words (Proverbs 5:3-20) the Holy Spirit by the mouth of Solomon warns against communication with a harlot or unfaithful wife:

```
For the lips of an immoral woman drip honey, 
And her mouth is smoother than oil;
But in the end she is bitter as wormwood, 
Sharp as a two-edged sword.
Her feet go down to death, 
Her steps lay hold of hell.
Lest you ponder her path of life-- 
Her ways are unstable; 
You do not know them.
Therefore hear me now, my children, 
And do not depart from the words of my mouth.
Remove your way far from her, 
And do not go near the door of her house,
Lest you give your honor to others, 
And your years to the cruel one;
Lest aliens be filled with your wealth, 
And your labors go to the house of a foreigner;
And you mourn at last, 
When your flesh and your body are consumed,
And say: «How I have hated instruction, 
And my heart despised correction!
I have not obeyed the voice of my teachers, 
Nor inclined my ear to those who instructed me!
I was on the verge of total ruin, 
In the midst of the assembly and congregation.»
Drink water from your own cistern, 
And running water from your own well.
Should your fountains be dispersed abroad, 
Streams of water in the streets?
Let them be only your own, 
And not for strangers with you.
Let your fountain be blessed, 
And rejoice with the wife of your youth.
As a loving deer and a graceful doe, 
Let her breasts satisfy you at all times; 
And always be enraptured with her love.
For why should you, my son, be enraptured by an immoral woman, 
And be embraced in the arms of a seductress?
```